# What 莲 means? does it has a "social" meaning, if it's used in everyday life?

Tags: meaning, idioms, culture

*I think that '莲' literally means "lotus" but I heard some people saying that it also has a bad meaning, if somebody calls you like that you should be offended. Can someone explain me why? Thank you so much.*

Answer (score 2):

i'm afraid there's no such bad meaning with 莲 in chinese,actually it's not a common word in daily life as it is not commonly seen.

however i'd say there's indeed a bad meaning if you insisted,莲 as a component of 白莲花 has two completely different senses of bitch and pure girl.the former  implies someone pretending and trying to make others believe her a pure one.

in other way you can also take it as homonym in 不要逼脸 which transform to 不要碧莲 that actually means 不要脸 or merely a joking phrase。

Comment: Oh, I see. Some people said it means something like "a person who fakes innocence/pretends to be a victim" or "someone stupid/dumb" and I was kinda confused. Thank you so much for your explanation!